# find a element in jQuery dialog after it opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I'm creating a dialog on the fly. What I'm trying to do next is to bind some of the inputs with `.datepicker()`, but I can't seem to find the inputs at all. What I'm I missing here?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2Kb4/1)

```
function createDialog(top, dialog_width, data) {
        $('<div></div>')
            .addClass('add-dialog')
            .appendTo('body')
            .dialog({
                title: 'test',
                closeText: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>',
                close: function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                },
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    //has the full html with the inputs
                    console.log(this);

                    //trying to get them
                    var inputs = $(this).find('input');
                    console.log(inputs.length);

                    //also tried this, no luck
                    //$(this).parent().promise().done(function() {
                    //    var t = $(this).find('input');
                    //});

                },
                modal: true,
                width: dialog_width,
                position: ['center', (top - 12)],
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false
            }).html(data);
    }
```

Comment: append the html(data) before open callback of dialog, you are not getting element coz there is no html in add-dialog div

Comment: @ramby, it does. `console.log(this);` shows full html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the initialization order.... add the html, then initialize the dialog

```
$('<div></div>').html(data).dialog({ /*opts*/})
```

You are adding the html after the dialog is initialized so the `open` event has already occurred and there is no element yet to be found

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k2Kb4/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: I can't get your example to log anything in console?

Comment: works fine for me in the demo. Are you using ajax to load it?

Answer (score 0):

You can asign a class to each element you need, something like:

```
<input type='text' class='needIt'/>
```

and then use:

```
$(this).find('.needIt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save reference to the jquery object after it has been inserted into DOM, then get reference to jquery UI dialog instance. And this instance has many useful properties. Example:

```
$('form').append($body); // I've appended dialog as last element inside form in my document, $body is markup, received from AJAX

$body.dialog({...}); // I've turned markup into jquery UI dialog

var dialogInstance = $body.dialog('instance'); // I receive reference to jquery UI dialog instance in any place, for instance, button click event

dialogInstance.uiDialogButtonPane.hide(); // I can access button pane in the dialog and many other objects, like caption area, etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

try this add html after appendTo()

```
function createDialog(top, dialog_width, data) {
        $('<div></div>')
            .addClass('add-dialog')
            .html(data)// added html here
            .appendTo('body')
            .dialog({
                title: 'test',
                closeText: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>',
                close: function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                },
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    //has the full html with the inputs
                    console.log(this);

                    //trying to get them
                    var inputs = $(this).find('input');
                    console.log(inputs.length);

                    //also tried this, no luck
                    //$(this).parent().promise().done(function() {
                    //    var t = $(this).find('input');
                    //});

                },
                modal: true,
                width: dialog_width,
                position: ['center', (top - 12)],
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false
            });
    }
```

Comment: `dialog` automatically does the append... how would original demo be working if this was needed?